# Global and session environment for the first session and following?

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export TEST=$1
tmux new-session -d -s $1
tmux send-keys -t $1:0 "printenv | grep TEST" C-m
```

Run:

```
# ./test.sh 123  #The tmux server is automatically launched
# ./test.sh 555
```

Results:

- `tmux a -t 123` shows `TEST=123`
- `tmux a -t 555` shows `TEST=123` instead of `TEST=555`!!!!

Why does my next TMUX sessions inherit all the environment variables of the first created session?

That's quite surprising, how can I do to stop this non-sense behavior?

https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#GLOBAL_AND_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT

> When the server is started, tmux copies the environment into the global environment; in addition, each session has a session environment. When a window is created, the session and global environments are merged. If a variable exists in both, **the value from the session environment is used**.

When I first run `123`, `TEST` is set GLOBAL for the tmux server. But when I run `555`, `TEST=123` should be replaced by the session env, but it isn't...

Comment: Running 2 different servers does the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506708/how-to-start-two-tmux-sessions-with-different-environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand reading the manual, this is the intended behavior.

When the server is (automatically) launched when you create your first session, the **global** environment is indeed created and get the `TEST` variable.

Why do you think that when you create the second session, the **session** environment will get `TEST`.

To set a session environment, you can use `set-environment`.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux new-session -d -s $1
tmux set-environment -t $1 TEST $1
```

run it

```
./test.sh 123
./test.sh 555
```

then you can look an environment using `show-environment`

```
tmux show-environment -t 123 TEST
tmux show-environment -t 555 TEST
```

---

**EDIT**

Window 0 created at `new-session` and thus does not get env set using `set-environment`.

I agree this is weird.

I think what you want can be achieve with (something like) this is .bashrc:

```
if [ -n "$TMUX" -a -n "$ENVFILE" ]; then
    source $ENVFILE
fi
```

and newsess.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sname=`basename $1`
tmux new-session -d -s $sname "ENVFILE=$1 bash"
tmux set-environment -t $sname ENVFILE $1
```

/tmp/env:

```
export A=1
export B=2
```

/tmp/env2:

```
export A=5
export B=5
```

then

```
./newsess.sh /tmp/env
./newsess.sh /tmp/env2
```

You got A=1 and B=2 in each window of session **env** and A=5 and B=5 in each window of session **env2**.

Comment: Because it's completely counterintuitive for linux dev, especially when coming from `screen`. It's such a weird design decision. The server has to be created at boot for a random session otherwise it might affect all the other sessions.

Comment: In your solution, TEST is set after the first command is executed. I'd like to at least configure the session environment from an env file `KEY=VALUE`, without needing to list or send one command per variable.

Comment: I meant "why do you think [...], according to the manual". What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can't you source a file or execute a script? Maybe update-environment?

Comment: The manual doesn't say a new session doesn't grab the environment. Every other tools do it, all the shells, screen, python etc..

Comment: I have an environment file (per line KEY=VALUE format) and I want to initialize the session with it, so that new windows inherit the environment. All the commands I run in each window require the environment variables. My question shows what I want to achieve and what I expect. `set-environment` is run after the new-session's command, then that's useless since the command won't be run under the environment I want.

Comment: 1. The fact that the manual doesn't say **not something** doesn't mean **something**. 2. "Every other [...]" seem to be a paralogism. 3. set-environment sets **session** environment. I don't see why it is useless. What **command** are you talking about. Since you launch the session using a script, you can do whatever you want, looping through variables in your environment file and use `set-environment`, for example. That's probably not the only solution.

Comment: 2. well, that's called UX, if your tool doesn't do what we can expect from years of experience with other more common tools, there is a UX design problem.

Comment: The actual command doesn't matter, eg. `tmux new-session -d -s sess_name anycommand_or_script.sh`, the cmd/script doesn't have the environment created after `new-session` with `set-environment`. Also `new-session -e` doesn't exist on centos 7's `tmux 1.7`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one, from all the questions I've read, nobody understands why it works like that and why it wasn't possible to just set env var before the window 0 is started. It is clearly not a natural behavior, thanks. All the added options seem to be the consequences of the original flawed design. Anyway, I'll do the trick with bash to add all the printenv into the session.

Comment: Right, I did not see about windows 0 automatically created and thus does not get session variable set after. I understand and agree now.

Comment: Actually I found a link (the only one among tens I've read) mentioning I can create several servers with different socket name. This will do the trick and keeps it intuitive. One server per session. I need to update tmux on centos 7 tho, but it'll be worth it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer.